# How to detect a potential overflow

Tags: c#

OK, consider the following scenario:

```
 public static bool TryGetNearestRationalNumber(double target, double precision, out RationalNumber nearest)
 {
     //implements continued fractions to solve the problem. Only relevant code is shown.

     var integerPart = (long)target; //necessary for algorithm
     var fractionalPart = target - integerPart; //necessary for algorithm,
     ....
 }
```

`RationaNumber` internally uses two `Int64` signed integers to represent numerator and denominator. I want my method to throw a `System.OverflowException` if the attempted number to approximate is greater or smaller than the biggest or smallest number that can be represented by `RationalNumber`, which are `long.MaxValue` and `long.MinValue`.

My first try was pretty straightforward and naive:

```
 public bool TryGetNearestRationalNumber(double target, double precision, out Foo foo)
 {
     //check overflow here
     if (target > long.MaxValue || target < long.MinValue)
         throw new OverFlowExcetpion();         

     //implements continued fractions to solve the problem. Only relevant code is shown.
     var integerPart = (long)target; //necessary for algorithm
     var fractionalPart = target - integerPart; //necesarry for algorithm,

     ...
 }
```

This fails miserable when I either call `TryGetNearestRationalNumber(1f + long.MaxValue, precision, nearest)` or `TryGetNearestRationalNumber(-1f + long.MinValue, precision, nearest)`. Evidently this is due to the fact that for such big or small numbers, `double` doesn't have enough resolution to detect the potential overflow and neither `if` condition resolves to `true`.

My second try was more of a hack (I find it kind of ugly) but considering what the algorithm needed to do, I could detect an overflow if `integerPart` and `target` didn't have the same sign; that had to necessarily mean an overflow had happened. So my second try looked like this:

```
 public bool TryGetNearestRationalNumber(double target, double precision, out Foo foo)
 {
     //implements continued fractions to solve the problem. Only relevant code is shown.
     var integerPart = (long)target; //necessary for algorithm

     if ((integerPart < 0 && target > 0) || (integerPart > 0 && target < 0)) //yuck!
         throw new OverFlowException();

     var fractionalPart = target - integerPart; //necesarry for algorithm,
 }
```

The problem is that this wont work either. It does work for maximum value overflows `TryGetNearestRationalNumber(1f + long.MaxValue, precision, nearest)` but fails miserably again with minimum value overflows `TryGetNearestRationalNumber(-1f + long.MinValue, precision, nearest)`. On top of that this solution is far from perfect, because given a large enough `target`, the overflow can happen without a change of sign.

I'm sure there has to be a completely evident and dumb way of doing this and I'm missing it completely. Can somebody please show me the way and end my misery on this particular problem?

Answer (score 2):

The [ckecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) keyword helps your code to catch if an overflow happens at runtime by throwing an `OverflowException`.

```
// Checked block. 
checked
{
    int i3 = 2147483647 + 10; // throws
    Console.WriteLine(i3);
}
```

---

Following the discussion with usr on your other thread, we can deduce that in order to capture the overflow for the lower bound of your long value in a double, you must go down to `1025d - long.MinValue`. So it looks like your lower bound must take into account the mantissa size of your decimal type in order to handle correctly casts back to `long`.

It is quite nasty as a workaround, and doesn't make for a very readable code...

Comment: Consider my scenario: I have a `double` typed argument and I have to figure out if that will overflow as a `long`. If I pass to the method `-1d + long.MinValue` I still won't get an `OverFlowException` even in a `checked` context when I cast it to long `(long)(-1d + long.MinValue)`. It does throw for `1d + long.MaxValue` though.

Comment: That is really strange: I'm looking into it right now, because I thought that the precision loss was coming from you keeping the `-1d + long.MinValue` in a double format, but precision loss is not caught by the checked keyword.

Comment: The code works if you write `var x = ((long)-1d + long.MinValue);`, it's awful.

Comment: Yes, that's because you're working in long for all members of the calculation, but `var x = (long)(-1d + long.MinValue);` doesn't throw, because the double to long conversion doesn't consider the data loss.

Comment: FrancescoDiLisi: yeah but that doesnt help me. I need to know if a `double` argument overflows. Your code is directly passing in a `long`.

Comment: I've posted another question about the wierd behavior of `checked` in a simplified scenario. In case you want to follow it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605603/checked-and-overflowexception-woes-in-c-sharp

Comment: Well I was reaching the same conclusion. The `checked` keyword logic doesn't work for non integer types. There is no way to check for overflows on decimal types unless you define hard limits by yourself :/