# Why does this checked calculation not throw OverflowException?

Tags: c#

Can somebody please explain the following behavior:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        checked
        {
            double d = -1d + long.MinValue; //this resolves at runtime to -9223372036854780000.00
            //long obviousOverflow = -9223372036854780000; //compile time error, '-' cannot be applied to operand of tpye ulong -> this makes it obvious that -9223372036854780000 overflows a long.
            double one = 1;
            long lMax = (long)(one + long.MaxValue); // THROWS
            long lMin = (long)(-one  + long.MinValue); // THEN WHY DOES THIS NOT THROW?
        }
    }
```

I don't undersant why I'm not getting an `OverFlowException` in the last line of code.

**UPDATE** Updated code to make it obvious that checked does through when casting a double to long except in the last case.

Comment: Double can store 15 significant digits.  The result of your calculation requires 19 significant digits to be precise.  So *inevitably* the result of your calculation is going to lose 4 digits of precision.  Whether that makes the result larger or smaller than the theoretical value is unpredictable.  Well, not with this code.

Comment: Hms, does it actually throw? I cannot get it to throw, I can get a compile time error, but no throwing =/ Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @HansPassant I can see that, but why `(long)(-one  + long.MinValue);` doesn't throw? It also suffers from same precision issue what you told!

Comment: Just reason it through.  You know the result is imprecise, so there are only 50% odds of it throwing an exception.  Whether it does is *not* predictable, it depends on whether the C# compiler or the jitter or the processor makes the calculation, which jitter you use, whether or not the optimizer is enabled, what other calculations are made in the method.  Seemingly innocent small changes produce a different outcome.

Comment: @HansPassant: But that is not the case. If I step in the debugger I know for sure that `(-one + long.MinValue)` is way off the correct value but its also way smaller than long.MinValue. I get consistently the value -9223372036854780000.00 which *should* throw when cast to `long` in a `checked` context. Also, `(long)(1d + long.MaxValue)` throws consistently.

Comment: No, you assume that what the debugger shows you is a precise representation for the binary value that's stored in the floating point processor register.  It is not.

Comment: @HansPassant: OK got you. So what should I expect in production? Will the exceptions be thrown incosistently? Is there anyway to make it consistent?

Comment: @InBetween Have a look at `BitConverter.GetBytes()`, it has helped me when I've been in similar situations.

Comment: I don't really understand why programmers want to check if their calculations went haywire with such precision.  If the result of a calculation is +/-9.0E18 then surely you already know you've got a junk result?  So just compare it to the largest possible value you find reasonable for whatever physical entity the number represents.

Comment: @HansPassant Its not wether its a junk result or not. Evidently in most scenarios it is, but I want to understand 1) Why the checked context was not throwing an overflow exception and 2) Inconsistent behavior is something that I think should be avoided if possible. If its not, then I can evidently live with it in this case, but nonethelss I'd like to know if its possible. The library does not model any physical entity, its a mathematical library. This came up while evaluating rational approximations to very large numbers.

Comment: Well, just never ever use floating point in a math library like that.  Arbitrary precision types are a-plenty, starting with .NET's System.Numerics.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating with `double` values (`-1d`). Floating point numbers do not throw on .NET. `checked` does not have influence on them in any way.

But the conversion back to `long` is influenced by `checked`. `one + long.MaxValue` does not fit into the range of `double`. `-one  + long.MinValue` does fit into that range. The reason for that is that signed integers have more negative numbers than positive numbers. `long.MinValue` has no positve equivalent. That's why the negative version of your code happens to fit and the positive version does not fit.

The addition operation does not change anything:

```
Debug.Assert((double)(1d + long.MaxValue) == (double)(0d + long.MaxValue));
Debug.Assert((double)(-1d + long.MinValue) == (double)(-0d + long.MinValue));
```

The numbers we are calculating are outside of the range where `double` is precise. `double` can fit integers up to 2^53 precisely. We have rounding errors here. Adding one is the same as adding zero. Essentially, you are computing:

```
var min = (long)(double)(long.MinValue); //does not overflow
var max = (long)(double)(long.MaxValue); //overflows (compiler error)
```

The add operation is a red herring. It does not change anything.

Comment: Then why does it through when doing `long lMax = (long)(one + long.MaxValue)`?

Comment: @InBetween it throws with `long lMin = (long)(-one + long.MinValue)` as well.

Comment: FrancescoDeLisi: It does not throw in my machine. VS 2010, Windows 7 32 bits

Comment: @InBetween neither when running?

Comment: Exactly. In my machine the addition resolves to a number that is way off because Double doesn't have the precision. But even though way off, the number is *lower* than long.MinValue so it should throw anyways. That's the whole point of the compile time error of applying - to a ulong that I've included in the question

Comment: @usr: not sure if your answer is still correct, lMax==lMin  but one throws, another doesn't: unchecked((long)(one + (double)long.MaxValue)) ==  (long)(-one  + long.MinValue) is true.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa if you apply unchecked overflow can happen and this result can appear. But the point of unchecked is to not allow overflow. So I don't see why this would make my statements incorrect. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think that one + long.MaxValue **does** fit into the range of double. What's more you are comparing bounds: long.MinValue - 1 is just as invalid as long.MaxValue + 1, their assymetry has nothing to do with their range

Comment: @samy `one + long.MaxValue` does fit into the range but not precisely. When converting back, you might get a different value (here, you don't - that's why it overflows). But for the negative value you get back a different value than you passed in - no overflow.

Comment: I really don't see it for now: from what I experimented the exception point triggers at -1025 when converting from double to long in the lower bound which doesn't make much sense and doesn't seem random. I'll hit my head against the problem again later

Comment: @samy 53 mantissa precision + 10 bits in the number 1024 are 63 bits. That's the number of unsigned bits in a long. 1025 is the first number using 11 bits (64 in total). That exceeds the long range. The numbers kind of make sense for that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some leeway in the conversion from double to long. If we run the following code:

```
checked {
    double longMinValue = long.MinValue;

    var i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        long test = (long)(longMinValue - i);
        Console.WriteLine("Works for " + i++.ToString() + " => " + test.ToString());
    }
}
```

It goes up to `Works for 1024 => -9223372036854775808` before failing with an `OverflowException`, with the -9223372036854775808 value never changing for i.

If we run the code unchecked, no exception is thrown.

This behavior is not coherent with the [documentation on explicit numeric conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx) that says:

> When you convert from a double or float value to an integral type, the
>   value is truncated. If the resulting integral value is outside the
>   range of the destination value, the result depends on the overflow
>   checking context. In a checked context, an OverflowException is
>   thrown, while in an unchecked context, the result is an unspecified
>   value of the destination type.

But as the example shows, the truncation doesn't occur immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the question:

> I don't undersant why I'm not getting an `OverFlowException` in the last
>   line of code.

Have a look at this line (the `1d` you are using is insignificant and can be removed, the only thing it provided was conversion to `double`):

```
var max = (long)(double)long.MaxValue;
```

It throws because the closest (I do not know the spec, so I won't go into what "closest" is here) double representation of `int64.MaxValue` is larger than the largest `int64`, ergo it cannot be converted back.

```
var min = (long)(double)long.MinValue;
```

For this line on the other hand the closest double representation is between `int64.MinValue` and 0 so it can be converted back to `int64`.

What I just said does not hold for all combinations of jitter, hardware etc, but I'm trying to explain what happens. Remember that in your case it is thrown because of the `checked` keyword, without it the jitter would just swallow it.

Also I would recommend you to have a look at `BitConverter.GetBytes()` to experiment what happens when you go from `double` to `long` and back with large number, also `decimal` and `double` is interesting :) (the byte representation is the only representation you can trust btw, don't use the debugger for precision when it comes to `double`)